# automated import from blogger

Tags: import, automatic-updates, blogger

I am looking for a way to make the Blogger importer tool run automatically to update a blog content category automatically.

I appreciate that Google does not like duplicate content, but the site I am making will not be a site that only has duplicate content. What my client wants is a means of consolidating all their content across the web in to one place- a bit like the way you can make your facebook updates go to twitter etc. Part of this is their Blogger blog, but also they will be posting things like their Soundcloud music and their Youtube videos and all sorts of other stuff. The 'Blog' section of the site is only a small part of this and the posts imported from blogger will be accompanied by site specific posts.

So just wondering if anyone has any smart ideas on how I could go about achieving this? Is this something I would have to do with a Cron job, or maybe it could happen in the background when someone visits the home page?

Any ideas most welcome :)

Comment: Rather than automatically importing why not consolidate to one WordPress site? For example import once in the beginning then just continue to blog via the WordPress site instead of blogger. This will eliminate multiple accounts for various sites for your client. If this make sense and moves things to one site instead of two.

Comment: Understand where you are coming from there, but this is not what they want to do, they want to have a Blogger site, a tumblr and everything else, they just don't want to have to do any extra work to maintain them all separately...

Comment: Frankly, if that's what they're going for then they don't understand the point of blogging/social media/Tumblr/etc in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I get where you are coming from. I put it the wrong way round in my last post, what they want to do is pull in all the stuff they work on in Soundcloud, YouTube Blogger etc into one place. Kind of like flavors.me does already but they need more developer flexibility, CMS features etc. They just dont want to write everything on all those sites and then write it again on the website...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to auto-import the Blogger RSS feed.  You'll set up a cron job in WordPress to check the Blogger site's feed for updates and, if they exist, create a new post with that content.

There are a handful of plugins already out there that will do this for you, but essentially, here's what you do:

- Every 1 hour/2 hours/6 hours/whatever, load the RSS feed from the remote site.
- Check to see if there are any new entries
- If there are, use `wp_insert_post()` to create a new post with the imported content

There's a premium plugin called [AutoBlogged](http://autoblogged.com/) that does this for you.

You can also use [Feed WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) to update your site from an RSS feed on whatever interval you want.